# Query Params getting lost with Redux-Persist and React-Router-Redux

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux, redux-persist

I'm trying to get an auth code sent from an api sent through query params:

`http://example.com?code=AUTH_CODE`

However when the page loads, it forwards to the url without I'm working in React-Redux with Redux-Persist and React-Router-Redux. I can find the query params in a previous state before "persist/REHYDRATE" but can't get persist to leave the routing reducer be. I believe Redux-Persist is persisting the route and eliminating the query params. This is what my logger output looks like:

[image: Can see the query params here]

I can see the query params at the 'prev state' where the arrow is, but it's gone by the below 'next state'

[image]

I've tried using blacklist, and redux-persist-transform-filter to blacklist 'routing' with no luck.

This is what my index.js looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import routes_design from './routes'

import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react'

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
}

const reducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer)

function configureStore () {
  let store = createStore(
    reducer,
    compose(...) // Middleware here removed for brevity
  )
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { persistor, store }
}

const { persistor, store } = configureStore()

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
       <Router history={history} routes={routes_design}/>
     </PersistGate>
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

registerServiceWorker()
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into a similar problem - I got it. I was blacklisting my routing reducer properly, but I needed to purge the persistor. It was getting suck with the store from before I implemented the blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you have update or are using react-router v4 then
I had a similar issue parsing callback string a facebookl url in my case is because I updated to the react-router v4 in which they stopped parsing query strings but there's a number of libraries to handle this, I used [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to solve this issue

You can check the github issue on the same: 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410

Comment: I believe my problem is with redux-persist though @iamcaleberic. I'm on v3.2.0 and I can see it getting parsed in my logger (ref the screenshots above). The problem is that I can't get redux-persist to blacklist the routing reducer.